# Combine Two SQL Query into 1

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question...

I want to combine two sql queries into one but the problem is that both these queries have GROUP BY in it.

Query 1:

```
SELECT   COUNT(users_survey_answers.ultimate_survey_code)
FROM     company,
         users_codes,
         users_survey_answers
WHERE    company.company_id = users_codes.company_id
  AND    users_codes.email = "test@gmail.com"
  AND    users_codes.company_id = users_survey_answers.company_id
  AND    users_survey_answers.completed = 0
GROUP BY users_codes.company_id
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT   COUNT(users_rewards.reward_id)
FROM     company, 
         users_codes, 
         users_rewards
WHERE    company.company_id = users_codes.company_id
  AND    users_codes.email = "test@gmail.com"
  AND    users_rewards.company_id = users_codes.company_id
  AND    redeemed = 0
GROUP BY users_codes.company_id
```

I appreciate the help.  I have tried so many solutions, still no help.

Thanks.

Comment: Both queries group by the same field - what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    company.company_id,
          users_pts.pts as CompanyPts,
          t1.ultimate_survey_code_count,
          t2.reward_id_count
FROM      company,
          users_codes
INNER JOIN (
          SELECT 
              company_id, 
              COUNT(ultimate_survey_code) AS ultimate_survey_code_count
          FROM users_survey_answers
          WHERE completed = 0
          GROUP BY company_id
          ) AS t1
       ON users_codes.company_id = t1.company_id
INNER JOIN (
          SELECT 
              company_id, 
              SUM(IF(redeemed = 0, 1, 0)) AS reward_redeem_zero_count,
              SUM(IF(redeemed = 0, 0, 1)) AS reward_redeem_not_zero_count
          FROM users_rewards
          GROUP BY company_id
          ) AS t2
       ON users_codes.company_id = t2.company_id
INNER JOIN users_pts
       ON users_codes.company_id = users_pts.company_id
WHERE     company.company_id = users_codes.company_id
  AND     users_codes.email = "test@gmail.com"
```

This is untested, but hope meets your need.

Comment: Quick Question: Can you help me figure out how to join the 2 queries in the original question along with this 1 query? SELECT pts as CompanyPts FROM users_pts, users_codes WHERE users_codes.company_id = users_pts.company_id AND users_codes.email = test@gmail.com

Comment: If the pts return one row on one users_codes.email, try my edited answer above...

Comment: Thanks. Another question: How do I return back a count for (reward_id) even if redeemed does not equal 0?  Right now COUNT() returns NULL but I would like it to return 0.

Comment: @user1025013 if you want to change NULL to zero you can simply use `IFNULL(field, 0) AS fieldname` or try my edited answer above which count the rewards both if redeemed = 0 and redeemed not 0.

Comment: Hey Thanks for all your help. I have a huge project I am working on and I am a beginner at SQL. Can you take a look at this new question I made? Thanks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640082/sql-combine-four-queries-into-1

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I took the libery of adding `company_id` to the selection. What good is it to group by company_id if you cannot tell afterwards which result belongs to which company. :)</strike>

```
select
  company_id,
  sum(code_count) as code_count,
  sum(reward_count) as reward_count
FROM
    (SELECT   
       users_codes.company_id,
       COUNT(users_survey_answers.ultimate_survey_code) as code_count,
       null as reward_count
    FROM     company,
             users_codes,
             users_survey_answers
    WHERE    company.company_id = users_codes.company_id
      AND    users_codes.email = "test@gmail.com"
      AND    users_codes.company_id = users_survey_answers.company_id
      AND    users_survey_answers.completed = 0
    GROUP BY users_codes.company_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   
      users_codes.company_id,
      COUNT(users_rewards.reward_id) as reward_count,
      null
    FROM     company, 
             users_codes, 
             users_rewards
    WHERE    company.company_id = users_codes.company_id
      AND    users_codes.email = "test@gmail.com"
      AND    users_rewards.company_id = users_codes.company_id
      AND    redeemed = 0
    GROUP BY users_codes.company_id) x
GROUP BY 
  company_id
```

Too cumbersome. You can write it like this.
I also took the liberty of introducing a more modern `INNER JOIN` as well as aliasing, but feel free to revert that.

```
SELECT
  c.company_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(ultimate_survey_code)
  FROM
    users_survey_answers a
  WHERE
    a.completed = 0 AND
    a.company_id = c.company_id) as answer_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(ultimate_survey_code)
  FROM
    users_rewards r
  WHERE
    r.redeemed = 0 AND
    r.company_id = c.company_id) as reward_count
FROM
  company c
  INNER JOIN users_code uc ON uc.company_id = c.company_id
WHERE
  uc.email = "test@gmail.com"
GROUP BY
  c.company_id
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. It is giving me row 1 and row 2 as NULL in reward_count

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I think it's quite a mess after all. I've posted a whole new query.

Comment: It needs to be users_codes instead of users_code..... Thanks a lot MAN! I really appreciate the help.  I thought I would be lucky to get 1 reply by tomorrow.

Comment: If I need to contact you in the future, can I get your email? If that is possible...

Comment: I'm afraid not. I won't have any time left if I start doing personal consults by e-mail. :D But I'm on SO quite a lot, as are thousands of others who are willing to help.

Comment: Quick Question: Can you help me figure out how to join the 2 queries in the original question along with this 1 query?

SELECT pts as CompanyPts FROM users_pts, users_codes WHERE 

users_codes.company_id = users_pts.company_id AND 

users_codes.email = test@gmail.com